# Mongoengine pre_delete FileField

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

I'm new to mongoengine. I am trying to get the pre_delete hook to delete a FileField storing in GridFS.

I am using Python 2.7.10, Mongo 3.4 and mongoengine 0.8.7.

Here is what I have.

```
import uuid

import mongoengine as me

class MyFiles(me.Document):
    meta = {"collection": "test"}
    guid = me.UUIDField(binary=False, required=True)
    my_file = me.FileField()

    @classmethod
    def pre_delete(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
        document.my_file.delete()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    me.connect(db='main', alias='default', host='localhost')

    m = MyFiles(guid=uuid.uuid4())
    m.my_file.new_file(content_type='text/plain')
    m.my_file.write("This is")
    m.my_file.write("my file")
    m.my_file.write("Hooray!")
    m.my_file.close()
    m.save()

    print(m.my_file.read())

    m.delete()
```

Now I am debugging with a breakpoint on m.delete()

my.file.read() worked.

[image]
There is a document in collection "test" that refers to the file in GridFS.
[image]

There is a file in fs.files.
[image]

And in fs.chunks.
[image]

Now I ran m.delete().
Collection "test" is empty.
[image]

fs.files is not empty. Neither is fs.chunks. The file remains.
[image]

According to [mongoengine docs for gridfs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/gridfs.html), I need to run m.my_file.delete() to delete the GridFS entry before deleting the MyFiles document. I have confirmed this works if I put m.my_file.delete() before m.delete() like so.

```
m.save()

print(m.my_file.read())

m.my_file.delete()
m.delete()
```

However I want it to run in pre_delete. This seems like the purpose of pre_delete. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem. I did not register the signal. This works:

```
import uuid

import mongoengine as me

class MyFiles(me.Document):
    meta = {"collection": "test"}
    guid = me.UUIDField(binary=False, required=True)
    my_file = me.FileField()

    @classmethod
    def pre_delete(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
        document.my_file.delete()

me.signals.pre_delete.connect(MyFiles.pre_delete, sender=MyFiles)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    me.connect(db='main', alias='default', host='localhost')

    m = MyFiles(guid=uuid.uuid4())
    m.my_file.new_file(content_type='text/plain')
    m.my_file.write("This is")
    m.my_file.write("my file")
    m.my_file.write("Hooray!")
    m.my_file.close()
    m.save()

    print(m.my_file.read())

    m.delete()
```